# 30 Meter in series LED SMD 5050 60 led/m 12v RGBW

Tags: power-supply, led, surface-mount, led-strip, rgb

I want to run 30 meter Led length in series in a room on the ceiling.

LED specifications (according to the supplier:)

- LED Type: 5050 RGBW LED Light Strip
- Quantity: 60 LEDs / Meter
- Working Input Voltage: DC12V
- Power: 35 - 40W
- LED strip light type: RGBW**

I have got following kit to run a 30 meter length of LED SMD 5050 60 led/m 12v strip.

- x6 5M Rolls/Rims 5050 RGBW LED Strip
- x1 25Amps AC110V/220V to DC 12V Power Supply Transformer
- x1 LED RGBW Wifi Controller
- x3 Mini LED RGBW Amplifier

Can someone please suggest that is the above kit enough for the purpose.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you stuck in your design? Are you able to work out the required current? You can delete many lines of the specification which are cluttering up your question: waterproof-ness, view angle, temperature, lifetime, WiFi and amplifier are all irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I see your edit but don't see your calculations or where you are stuck?

Comment: It's pretty clear that 6 x 5m = 30m, so that's right.  6 x (40W / 12V) = 20A, so that's OK.  But I have no idea what the WiFi Controller or Amplifier are supposed to do.

Comment: OK, but your question doesn't make clear what you are asking. You're hardly likely to get an answer to the WiFi controller and amplifier because you have supplied no details. In any case that would be a question about the **use** of electronic devices and they're off-topic on this site so it's likely that your question will be closed.

Comment: Sorry my mistake for not making it clear. Supplier has mentioned that SMD5050 60Led/meter has 35-40W, whereas I am searching online and most of the searches are coming up 72W onwards for the same strip so is it possible that supplier made a mistake in putting correct Watts of the strip?

Comment: Wifi controller is to control the strip via app and Amplifiers are for amplifying the RGBW signals for longer lengths. My question is when I am searching online it says put RGBW amplifier after every 5 meter. But supplier of my kit has made a 30 meter kit with only 3 amplifiers so is anyone here clarify me that whether these 3 amplifier would be enough or shall I put 1 every 5 meters?

Answer (score 0):

Please do pay attention to the voltage drop over longer lengths of LED strip. For longer strips, it might be a better idea to run them in parallel. I'm not sure if this is needed for your strip as I usually tend to use short strips, but it's something to consider.
[This](https://www.flexfireleds.com/led-strip-light-voltage-drop-what-is-voltage-drop/) is what I meant.

Comment: Try being more careful with the spelling.

Comment: To control the voltage drop I am putting amplifiers, How do I run parallel when I have to go across the ceiling? Can you please suggest how to run parallel across the ceiling?

Comment: They demonstrate it really nicely on that site. Split the run in half and put the power supply in the middle of the strips. This would also mean splitting the current running through the strip in half. This (in my mind, correct me if I'm wrong) decreases power loss in the strip $$P = I^2R$$ and thus heat generated. As you might know, heat can reduce an LED's lifespan and it can also soften up the glue. That is also a good bit of advice, use proper glue! The glue on the strip isn't the best and might not stick to the ceiling properly.